# Sqoooing data to HBase and integrated with Hive is having performance impact

Tags: hbase, hive, sqoop

We are sqooping the oracle tables to HBase and created mapping tables in Hive, and it seems while we are sqooping, all the data is going to one region, and hence when I query on hive only one map taks is executing for fetching the records.

is there any way this can be handled for increasing the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forcing the table to split?

If your data is small (less than 1 GB, or whatever your default minimum region size is), then you will only get one region on import.  You could force HBase to split the table into multiple regions, but you might not notice much improvement if your data is small.

There has historically been a lot of overhead in M/R jobs. Future versions of Hive should help, but the improvements probably haven't made it into the stable CDH distributions yet.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried force splitting of tables, and the number of mappers increased, but when I measure the performance of plain hive with hbase table after splitting, it is still taking more execution time than execution time on Hive.